# DNS port listener not receiving connections

Tags: python, dns, port, virtualbox, listener

My objective is to build a server socket listening on DNS port for connections, without responding anything, in order to collect some informations about IP addresses that are looking for DNS servers. The only thing I need to collect is the source IP. I wrote this code:

```
import socket


def create_socket():
    global host
    global port
    global s
    try:
        host = ''
        port = 53
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    except socket.error as msg:
        print('Socekt creation error:' + str(msg))

def bind_socket():
    try:
        print('Binding socket to port: ' + str(port) + ', Host: ' + str(host))
        s.bind((host, port))
    except socket.error as msg:
        print('Socket Binding error: ' + str(msg))


def socket_receive():
    while True:
        msg = s.recvfrom(1024)
        print('IP: ' + str(msg[1]) + ',   DATA: ' + msg[0].decode(encoding='cp1252', errors='ignore'))  

def main():
    create_socket()
    bind_socket()
    socket_receive()

main()
```

Unfortunately, I have to run this on a VirtualMachine using VirtualBox. I created a port forwarding rule for the port 53 on my router and I think I did it right, because the site "https://canyouseeme.org/" tells me that my ISP is not blocking the port. I created port forwarding rule on the VirtualMachine, so that all the traffic on the port 53 of the host will be redirected to the guest (where my program is). This is what I hope at least. I created a rule even in Windows Firewall allowing connections for the port 53. Finally, I used *iptables* to allow incoming traffic on the port 53 of my VirtualMachine. I still don't get anything. Probably I'm missing something, maybe I have to use *dnslib* in python in order to "attract" connections. Or I need to configure something more on Windows or on the router. Maybe I'm missing some important concepts.
**Why I don't get any connections?**

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e0ce:c8f6:a594:f24d%17
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter Connessione alla rete locale (LAN)* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Connessione alla rete locale (LAN)* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.name
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d03d:c2c9:163e:3eb6%6
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.11
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::b239:56ff:fea9:f35e%6
                                       192.168.1.1

Ethernet adapter Connessione di rete Bluetooth 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> netstat -na|findstr 53
  TCP    0.0.0.0:53             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5353           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5354         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  UDP    0.0.0.0:53             *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*
  UDP    192.168.1.11:5353      *:*
  UDP    192.168.56.1:5353      *:*
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*
  UDP    [::]:5355              *:*
  UDP    [::1]:5353             *:*
```

UFW on the guest:

```
diego@diego-VirtualBox:~$ sudo ufw status
[sudo] password di diego: 
Stato: attivo

A                          Azione      Da
-                          ------      --
53                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
19                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5353                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
123                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
53 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
19 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5353 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
123 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

ifconfig on the guest

```
diego@diego-VirtualBox:~$ sudo ifconfig
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::7059:da6f:6a4a:8f4e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:34:d5:6d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 395  bytes 307669 (307.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 278  bytes 33866 (33.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Loopback locale)
        RX packets 35  bytes 3215 (3.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 35  bytes 3215 (3.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

iptables on guest:

```
diego@diego-VirtualBox:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
```

Comment: The problem is not in the code, it seems to work fine. In that case, can you share your network setup? The IP's of your host and guest, and the mode in which your created network interface card for guest in VM. Try to do a hierarchical check, start from guest and then from the host machine, and then from another node which is in the same subnet as your host.

Comment: Added all informations I think can be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to debug this is to use wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org/#download) or another packet sniffer .  You can install it on both your windows host and the guest instance.  Assuming your network is like this:

```
                                ---------------------------
------------      --------      |         |---------------|
|dns client| ---- |router| ---- |win host | guest instance| 
------------      --------      ---------------------------
```

1. Listen for tcp 53 packets on the windows host's lan adapter (192.168.1.11). If no packets show up there, you have a problem with port forwarding/firewall or win host firewall. Keep in mind your home router may be acting as a DNS server and swallowing the packets.
2. Listen for tcp 53 packets on the guest instance.  (enp0s3) If you see packets at the windows host level, but not the guest, you can try switching the adapter type used bridged instead of NAT or visa versa.

Also, it's best to debug with your DNS client inside the router first, to be sure it's actually making requests to your honeypot.  If you're using nslookup or other standard client, you'll need to make sure you've set your windows host as the domain controller.  e.g.

```
% nslookup 
> server 192.168.1.1
Default server: 192.168.1.1
Address: 192.168.1.1#53
>
```

If all that works, I guess people simply aren't probing your network or your ISP has smart intrusion prevention that doesn't stop canyouseme, but stops dns scans ala netcat.